# Java JFrame inheriting components from another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, netbeans, jframe

We have a form design, where many of the components are the same (navigating in a table, ResultSet etc.) The idea is to create a template, and every form would inherit from this template. Problem is: when I change the

```
    public class TestForm extends javax.swing.JFrame { ...
```

to

```
    public class TestForm extends Template { ...
```

the components in the Template form doesn't show up in the designer. Is there any solution to make them show up, and is it a good idea at all to do this?

Comment: Can you show the code inside `TestForm` and `Template`?

Comment: *"JFrame inheriting components from another JFrame"* I'd recommend reworking the 'template' into a factory method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no solution** for you.

Even if you find away to show it in designer there will be not much use for it because you cant edit it. Netbeans know nothing about architecture of your `Template`. This mean it doesn't know how to reflect changes in desiner to changes in code.